# Pick a random .mp3 file to autoplay from a list of urls on page load?

Tags: html, autoplay

Right now I have this

```
<audio autoplay>
  <!-- <source src="https://a.pomf.cat/vmrlef.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">--> <!--  escape through the snow -->
 <!-- <source src="https://files.catbox.moe/vif2j1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> <!-- sea map -->
 <source src="https://files.catbox.moe/4abc2w.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> <!-- ミク - prblm- -->
</audio>
```

which I have no idea how to make it select each one randomly on page load up, is there a way to like have a list and then make source src choose from a list randomly on each reload? pretty new to html and any help would be much appreciated!! ^^

Comment: you can make an array of the urls, and on page load, you can change the src of the source tag by getting a random url out of the array.

Comment: hey, any basic idea how to do that or point me in the right direction? im pretty confused on how to do this exactly

Answer (score 0):

Like this

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6opnhymz/

```js
const audioUrls = ["https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3",
"https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3",
"https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3"];

const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*audioUrls.length); // random number from 0 to length of array
const audio = new Audio(); // an audio object
const loadedAudio = () => audio.play(); // what happens after the audio successfully has been found

document.body.appendChild(audio); // add it to the page
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', loadedAudio, false); // add the event that will play, here "can it play?"
console.log(`Playing #${rnd}:${audioUrls[rnd]}`); // for us to see it works
audio.src = audioUrls[rnd]; // actual trigger to play the audio
audio.load(); // iOS may need this
```

Comment: hey thanks! this seems to work on the fiddle, but i cant seem to get it to work on my web page, i put it in a <script> </script> block in my .html file, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: No, the code is droppable  - look in the console / network tab to see.
the first file YOU posted does not exist

Comment: `const audioUrls = ["https://files.catbox.moe/vif2j1.mp3", "https://files.catbox.moe/4abc2w.mp3"];` should work

Comment: alright thanks, it seems i did get an error in the network tab, i put the songs you provided since i know they work for the sake of testing, 

Uncaught TypeError: document.body is null
    <anonymous> http://localhost/test.html:41
test.html:41:1
    <anonymous> http://localhost/test.html:41

 any idea why this is happening? i think it has something to do with line 41, document.body.appendChild(audio); 
but I dont know why :(

Comment: Do you have a body tag? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: hey, i have a body tag, idk what i did exactly but it seems to work now ^^ thank you!!